# plotting a 3D bubble graph on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, 3d, scale

I am currently trying to plot a 3D bubble graph with 2 (then later i will try with 3) axes, as in excel, but on R (here is an example of the 3D bubble plot i am trying to plot) :
https://fr.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2017-excel-create-bubble-chart.html

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(plot_3D, aes(x = var_2020_2021_valeur, y = var_2020_2021_CA)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Specialite, size = CA.annee.N), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07",
                               "#FFB5C5", "#BF87B3", "#7F5AA2", "#3F2D91", "#000080",
                               "#2468A0", "#a32cc4", "#9073db", "#c51f5d",
                               "#5800ff", "#4455ff", "#48ff50")) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12)) + # Réglage de la plage de tailles des points
  ylim(-100, 100) + 
  xlim (-100, 100) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent)
```

I get the following message of error :

```
"Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', 
which
will replace the existing scale.
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', 
which
will replace the existing scale."
```

Even when i abandon the two last lines of code, it doesn't work...

Here is the structure of my dataset plot_3D :

```
structure(list(Specialite = c("ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", "Autres", 
"CHIRURGIE GENERALE ET VISCERALE", "CHIRURGIE PLASTIQUE", "GASTRO ENTEROLOGIE", 
"GYNECOLOGIE OBSTETRIQUE", "IMAGERIE", "MAXILLO STOMATO", "MEDECINE GENERALE et 
INTERNE", 
"OPHTALMOLOGIE", "ORL", "ORTHOPEDIE", "PNEUMOLOGIE", "URGENTISTE", 
"UROLOGIE"), CA.annee.N = c(64310L, 25298L, 1205537L, 42020L, 
3694964L, 344370L, 3454L, 588033L, 228439L, 1849804L, 27358L, 
2739286L, 0L, 916L, 432907L), Nombre.de.sejours.annee.N = c(171L, 
34L, 1504L, 56L, 9224L, 682L, 9L, 1103L, 888L, 2276L, 57L, 4068L, 
0L, 2L, 720L), CA.annee.N.1 = c(50135L, 454L, 790559L, 15531L, 
2644858L, 304242L, 3026L, 402195L, 459813L, 1308933L, 20597L, 
2269691L, 0L, 3901L, 318352L), Nombre.de.sejours.annee.N.1 = c(150L, 
1L, 1067L, 25L, 7276L, 627L, 9L, 802L, 1918L, 1693L, 43L, 3519L, 
0L, 7L, 547L), CA.annee.N.2 = c(48583L, 453L, 941610L, 16675L, 
3140507L, 385813L, 2950L, 642017L, 691982L, 1704005L, 51602L, 
2261368L, 7145L, 4648L, 308169L), Nombre.de.sejours.annee.N.2 = c(154L, 
1L, 1264L, 28L, 8317L, 831L, 8L, 1286L, 3231L, 2269L, 127L, 3610L, 
26L, 10L, 551L), CA_par_sejour_N = c(376.081871345029, 744.058823529412, 
801.553856382979, 750.357142857143, 400.581526452732, 504.941348973607, 
383.777777777778, 533.121486854034, 257.251126126126, 812.743409490334, 
479.964912280702, 673.374139626352, NaN, 458, 601.259722222222
), CA_par_sejour_N1 = c(334.233333333333, 454, 740.917525773196, 
621.24, 363.504398020891, 485.234449760766, 336.222222222222, 
501.490024937656, 239.735662148071, 773.14412285883, 479, 644.981813015061, 
NaN, 557.285714285714, 581.99634369287), CA_par_sejour_N2 = c(315.474025974026, 
453, 744.944620253165, 595.535714285714, 377.600937838163, 464.275571600481, 
368.75, 499.235614307932, 214.169606932838, 750.993829881005, 
406.314960629921, 626.417728531856, 274.807692307692, 464.8, 
559.290381125227), var_2020_2021_valeur = c(0.125207553640259, 
0.638896087069189, 0.0818395145215454, 0.207837780659878, 0.101999119223065, 
0.0406131494220115, 0.141440846001322, 0.063074957314078, 0.0730615704860669, 
0.051218505658529, 0.00201443064864667, 0.0440203522616658, NaN, 
-0.178159446295822, 0.0330987964754596), var_2020_2021_CA = c(0.282736611149895, 
54.7224669603524, 0.524917178856986, 1.70555662867813, 0.397036816343259, 
0.131895004634469, 0.141440846001322, 0.462059448774848, -0.503191514811456, 
0.413215191304673, 0.328251687138904, 0.206898207729598, NaN, 
-0.765188413227378, 0.35983753832236)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Could anyone help ?

Comment: Try e.g. `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-1, 1))` to set the limits without getting a warning and as the range of your data is from -1 to 1 set the limits to this range.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `xlim` and `ylim` because they can be used when you don't specify anything else on your axis. So your could add the limits to both `scale_*_continuous` in the `limits` arguments like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(plot_3D, aes(x = var_2020_2021_valeur, y = var_2020_2021_CA)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Specialite, size = CA.annee.N), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07",
                                "#FFB5C5", "#BF87B3", "#7F5AA2", "#3F2D91", "#000080",
                                "#2468A0", "#a32cc4", "#9073db", "#c51f5d",
                                "#5800ff", "#4455ff", "#48ff50")) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12)) + # Réglage de la plage de tailles des points
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-100, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-100, 100))
p
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the problem with this is that i need to rescale the axes... they go up to 10 000% when i would like them to go from -100% to 100%